# How can I automate sending mail using a script?

Tags: command-line, email, mail-user-agent

I have in the past heard of using `nail` for this task, but I can't seem to find it for my distribution (Ubuntu 11.04) in any of the repositories. What program can I use to one-off emails from a shell like so:

```
send-mail -to me@email.com -file attachment.zip -message "Hello World"
```

Is there a program out there through which I can script mail sending as above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nail` was renamed to [Heirloom mailx](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html).  For Ubuntu, you want to install the [heirloom-mailx](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/mail/heirloom-mailx) package, and then read the [Sending mail from scripts](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx/mailx.1.html#30) section of the manpage.

Comment: Where is the `mail.rc` file stored? I'd like to store my account info in there.

Comment: @TK, do you mean `/etc/nail.rc` (note the `n`) or `~/.mailrc`?  See the [env vars & files sections](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx/mailx.1.html#19) of the mailx manpage.

Comment: `~/.mailrc`. Thanks, I've got it all configured now! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ls -ltr | mail -s "Files in sys" yourmail@domain.com`